# Can we choose $g$ so that $\|(g\widehat{(f^{3})})^{\vee}\|_{L^{p}} \leq C \|g_{1}f\|_{L^{2}}^{r} \|(g_{2}\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{s}}$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, problem-solving, convolution

Let  $f, f^{2}, f^{3}\in L^{q}(\mathbb R)\cap C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ where $ q\geq p, \ \text{and}$ and $C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ is the class of continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

**My Questions**:

> (I) Can we expect to choose $0\neq g \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ (may be depending on given $f$) so that 
>   $$\|(g\widehat{(f^{3}})^{\vee}\|_{L^{p}} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{2}}^{r} \|(g\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{s}}$$ for some $1\leq p \leq 2,$ and for  **some**  $r \geq 1, s\geq p$? (where $C$ is some constant)\
>
> (II) Or, Can we expect to choose $0 \neq g= g_{1}g_{2} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with $g_{1}, g_{2} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with $g_{1}\leq 1$  so that 
>   $$\|(g\widehat{(f^{3})})^{\vee}\|_{L^{p}} \leq C \|g_{1}f\|_{L^{2}}^{r} \|(g_{2}\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{s}}$$ for some $1\leq p \leq 2,$ and for  **some**  $r \geq 1, s\geq p$?

[where $\widehat{(f^{3})}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f^{3}$ and $(g\widehat{(f^{3})})^{\vee}$ denotes the inverse Fourier transform of $g\widehat{(f^{3})}$; and $ \ C_{c}(\mathbb R)$ is the class of smooth functions with compact support]
[Side remark: see the related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226607/g-widehatff2-vee-l2-leq-c-f-l2r-g-hatf/1226662?noredirect=1#comment2495275_1226662)]

Any ideas or comments would be appreciated.
Thanks,